# How to loop in reactJS in table cell

Tags: reactjs

**How should I loop roles for each project in a row?**

I want to set roles in each cell for each project. I currently have a problem with syntax as this is my first time developing in reactJS.

```
render() {
            ...

            <Table
                resourceName="projects"
                columns={[
                    {
                        Header: 'Name',
                        accessor: 'name',
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Client',
                        accessor: 'client.name',
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Type',
                        accessor: 'type',
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'roles',
                        Header: 'Roles',
                        accessor: 'roles',
                        Cell: (props: { value: Array<{name: string}> }) => {
                            console.log(args);
                            return ',';
                        },
                    },
                ]}
            />
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it in accessor, not in Cell.

```
accessor: d => d.roles.map(role => role.name).join(', ')
```